# Mail on my Mac Pro running the latest update of High Sierra (newest OS I can use) keeps crashing when I use "Select All" to empty the trash

Tags: mail.app, trash

Application Specific Information:
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndexedSubscript:]: index 9223372036854775807 beyond bounds [0 .. 1]'
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
abort() called

Mail does not crash when I delete each email in the trash individually, only when I select them all then hit "delete." I have tried to delete the mail preferences, rebuilt the mailbox, deleted/reinstalled the account, reset the VRAM, erased the disk and reinstalled High Sierra (then restored from CCC5), ran disk utility from Recovery Drive, called AppleCare (very dismissive of my "obsolete" Mac Pro), booted into Safe Mode (same problem).

Comment: I have an old iMac and my system software is High Sierra, that's as far as I can go.  I just tried to replicate your problem. I went to the mail and I had over 100 messages in my Trash Can.  I opened the trash, selected all, and deleted them all with no problem. So what's the difference between our systems.

Comment: Updated EFI and SMC firmware so my 2009 Mac Pro can run High Sierra with an Nvidia graphics card. Everything running smoothly except for this weird bug in my Mail app. Is there a way to delete the Mail app and reinstall? Apple won't help me because they say my computer is obsolete.

Comment: When you rebuilt the mailbox did you also get it to re-index? Quit mail, then ~/Library/Mail/V6/MailData/ delete all the Envelope Index files [dupe to desktop first for safety] & re-launch Mail. The rebuild may take some time.

Comment: I have a 2010 iMac and mine is "obsolete" also!  i know how you feel...

Comment: @Tetsujin, I think that worked! This is the first time I've been able to select all mail in the Trash and delete it without a crash... for months. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: Glad it worked - let me quickly drop that into an actual Answer :)

Comment: @Tetsujin I spoke too soon. The crashes are happening again. When I delete the Envelope Index files, I can empty the trash once, but then the crashes reappear. There's a bug in there somewhere. I may have to erase my drive and reinstall High Sierra again. But then when I restore my data the bug will probably return. Sigh.

Comment: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndexedSubscript:]: index 9223372036854775807 beyond bounds [0 .. 1]'

Comment: As your last restore was from CCC, I'd try again - but this time after your fresh install, migrate from Time Machine. I can't think of another way to 'sanitise'. CCC will just put everything back exactly as it was, Migration should include some sanity checks… might just make the difference.

Comment: Good idea. I'll try this weekend.

Comment: Deleted my drive, reinstalled High Sierra, ran High Sierra updates, restored from Time Machine, and tried emptying the Mail Trash. Crashed again. Deleted all Envelope Index files again and was able to empty the trash successfully (no crash). But I'm expecting the mysterious crashes to return as before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you rebuilt the mailbox did you also get it to re-index?

Quit mail, then `~/Library/Mail/V6/MailData/` delete all the Envelope Index files [duplicate to the desktop first for safety] & re-launch Mail.

The rebuild may take some time